# How to create a new instance of DbContext with a specific connection string as constructor parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have such constructor of ApplicationDbContext class (I think quite standard one)

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
{
}
```

How I can create a new class instance with a specified connection string?

```
ApplicationDbContext   applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext (??);
```

Comment: Why do you want to achieve that? Context is already loaded and register in start-up.cs file itself.

Comment: @KiranJoshi Good question:) Inside a class that implements the IEmailSender interface, I would like to save the sent e-mails. And since this is an interface, I can't change the constructor

Comment: That you can achieve separately as well. Call your send email method from the respective method and from that method itself save your email data. If you want than I can provide you an example of same.

Comment: @KiranJoshi I think that i know how it should looks but if you can pls put example. Still such approach need change at any place that that method is called, instead making modification at one place

Answer (score 1):

You can save your email data like below:

```
/// <summary>
        /// SentBulkEmail to recipient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="emailModel"></param>
        /// <param name="sentBy"></param>
        public async Task<CustomResponseModel> SentBulkEmail(SendEmailModel emailModel, int sentBy = 0)
        {
            CustomResponseModel response = new CustomResponseModel();
            try
            {
                List<EmailSentHistoryModel> lstEmailSentHistory = new List<EmailSentHistoryModel>();
                Parallel.ForEach(emailModel.Recipient, (item) =>
                {
                    EmailSentHistoryModel historyModel = new EmailSentHistoryModel();
                    historyModel.EmailTemplateId = emailModel.EmailTemplateId;
                    historyModel.IsSent = Utilities.SendEmail(item, emailModel.Description, emailModel.Subject);
                    historyModel.Recipient = item;
                    historyModel.Sentdate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    historyModel.Sentby = sentBy;
                    lstEmailSentHistory.Add(historyModel);
                });
                response = await _emailTemplateRepository.SaveEmailSentHistory(lstEmailSentHistory);
                response.Message = "Email sent successfully!!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.IsSuccess = false;
                response.Message = Constant.ServerError;
                _logger.LogError("{0}: SentBulkEmail() : {1}", Constant.ServiceError, ex.Message);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Below is Email sent method:

```
public static bool SendEmail(string emailAddress, string body, string subject)
        {
            var _logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(ConfigItems.From, emailAddress))
                {
                    mail.Subject = subject;
                    mail.Body = body;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()
                    {
                        Host = ConfigItems.Host,
                        EnableSsl = true
                    };
                    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(ConfigItems.From, ConfigItems.Password);
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Port = ConfigItems.Port;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex.Message.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

You can see in **`SentBulkEmail`** I used that method to get whether email and sent or not and also save the data from their as well.